# Filter dataframe base on duplicate column values

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that i have this data,

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,1,1,6,7],'Sales':[2,3,4,2,8]})
```

[image]

Is there a filter such that it will output a dataframe such that the `Id` are the same? See expected output below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try

```
data=data[data.Id.duplicated(keep=False)]
   Id  Sales
0   1      2
1   1      3
2   1      4
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! Additinal question if it's okay, how do you format a dataframe in a markdown?

Comment: @BenjCabalonaJr. you mean how I get the dataframe ? readclipboard ?

Comment: Anyway thanks again. Stackoverflow won't let me accept the answer yet. I have to wait 10 more minutes. Cheers mate.